# In Bootstrap, how do I get my stepper to left align?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is some Codepen code:

https://codepen.io/thejohnsmith/pen/yYZPPW

I would like the cirlced "1" to be left aligned.

I've tried changing:

`<div class="stepper">`

to

`<div class="stepper pull-left">`

but that results in:

[image]

which isn't what I want because it shrinks the stepper size.

How do I get my stepper to left align without affecting the size?

Answer (score 2):

This works as I tested:

```
<div class="stepper float-left">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.stepper .nav-tabs [data-toggle='tab'] {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.stepper .nav-tabs > li:after {
  left: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
.stepper .nav-tabs [data-toggle='tab'] {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.stepper .nav-tabs > li:after {
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.stepper .nav-tabs [data-toggle='tab'] {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
margin: 20px 0px;
border-radius: 100%;
border: none;
padding: 0;
}

.stepper .nav-tabs > li:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
background: #f1f1f1;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
top: 30px;
/* left: 50%; */ //comment left in
z-index: 1;
}
```